# edge animate - limitar area mover objeto

Tags: microsoft-edge

Tenho um symbol no edge com função "drag" (mouseover-mover com mouse), agora quero limitar qual é a área, dentro do meu documento, em que será possível movê-lo.

Por enquanto esse e o código que tenho:

```
function(sym, e)
// insert code to be run when the symbol is created here
    yepnope({nope:['jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js'], complete: init});

function init(){
    sym.$('car').draggable();
    sym.$('car2').draggable();
}
```

que seria para movimentar o simbolo ('car').

Agora preciso de ajuda em como escrever o codigo para limitar a area onde sera possivel arrastar o objeto.
Grata

Comment: Clique em editar e poste uma parte do que você já fez, Dica, não precisa por texto como Ola! alguem saberia me ajudar, ... agradeco desde ja!

Comment: Coloca por favor o código que tens para podermos ajudar de maneira mais concreta.

Comment: // insert code to be run when the symbol is created here
yepnope({nope:['jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js'], complete: init});

function init(){
sym.$('car').draggable();
sym.$('car2').draggable();
} a ideia e fazer com que os objetos "car" e "car2" possam ser movimentados no eixo x mas nao no eixo y (ate o limite do stage) grata